# My Laravel mail queue gets proccessed but don't send email

Tags: php, laravel, queue

please some one should help ive done all required to setup my mail queue.

on my route:

```
Route::get('/test-mail', function () {
 Mail::to('***********@xxxx.com')->queue( new App\Mail\testMail()); 
 echo "sent";
});
```

the mail is queued and stored in the DB and with my listener, i can see it is processed successfully but the mail for reasons i don`t know, is not received at my mailbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXAy.png)

Comment: Which `MAIL_HOST` are you using? Check .env file

Comment: that of my cpanel

Comment: it works using normal send for laravel mailer but not the same when i use queue

Comment: do you see any failed jobs?

Comment: no. on my terminal, my listener shows proccessed

Comment: How are you running laravel queue are you using php artisan queue:work command.

Comment: yeah am using php artisan queue:work command and it shows on my terminal proccessed.